# grpc official example from their website doesn't work

Tags: python, grpc

I am following the exact example here on gRPC official website 
https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python/

But when I run "python greeter_server.py", I get an error that I don't know how to interpret it.

Here is the error message:

```
No address added out of total 1 resolved". "os_error": Address already in use", "syscall": bind"
```

Comment: try changing  `server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50055')`

Comment: @eyllanesc yes that was it. It worked. Thanks

Comment: Surely you have a service using port 50051, so you must use another port as indicated.